# Does an app server require NGINX or Apache?

Tags: python, apache, kotlin, nginx, networking

I am working an Android app for commercial usage, but no experience in this, so requesting help from the community.
I have just now purchased a VPS to serve my android app clients.
The app and server are both written in Kotlin and use KTor for http connection.
The server also connects to Firebase Authentication and a third party REST API using Python.
I am also listening to Webhooks from Stripe, which needs a https server with public domain name.
So far I have run localhost to run my app, but now I want to deploy to VPS server.
Do I need to install NGINX or Apache server to run my server on production for serving 10,000 clients daily?
I need https connections for connecting with app as well as Stripe.

Comment: Do you _need_ to? No. Are there reasons why it's commonly done? Yes. IMHO this question is asking for quite opinionated answers, (borderline: software recommendation) with not even enough information: 100000 clients - per minute, day, year? Can your app servers handle https?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Olaf. Actually I dont know what I am doing. I only know how to code, but dont know networking and deployment. See my edits in the question.

Comment: The description of the nginx tag recommends some other other Stack Exchange sites where this question might be more on-topic: [Super User](https://superuser.com), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), or [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'll the avoid the trap of giving an opinion of which of nginx/Apache is better; suffice to say I have used both and they are both mature products and very likely to meet your requirement to use them as reverse proxies.  I recommend you make your choice the way you might make other choices on areas you know better: what is the documentation like, what's the support from the community and so on.